# cant require canvacord in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

when i try to use const Canvas = require("canvacord") it gives this error

```
Error: libuuid.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/bot/node_modules/canvas/lib/bindings.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
Hint: hit control+c anytime to enter REPL.
```

is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Due to a lack of context and instructions I was unable to reproduce your issue. Although, assuming that you are using [Repl.it](https://replit.com), there is a comment about a similar issue available on [Github](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1893#issuecomment-1096988007):

> If you are facing this error at replit
> Follow this steps to fix it:
>
> 1. Click on three dots and then click on show hidden files
> 2. Go to file name 'replit.nix'
> 3. now under deps add: `pkgs.libuuid`
> 4. now after deps go to a fresh line (make sure there are no syntax conflicts), and paste this:
>    `env = { LD_LIBRARY_PATH = pkgs.lib.makeLibraryPath [pkgs.libuuid]; };`
> 5. Tada  your error is fixed, enjoy and thank me later :)

If this doesn't work, make sure you installed `libuuid` which is a dependency of `node-canvas` which itself is a dependency fo `canvacord`. Should be already installed on most Linux machines but maybe it's not... Run: `apt-get install libuuid1`